# Turn off jQuery events on window resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, coffeescript, onresize

So I currently have a website which looks like this:
[image: my website]

And on mobile the content collapses so that it looks like this:
[image: my website on iOs]

Which is precisely how I want it. Great! However, I don't want the sections to still be collapsible on larger screen sizes.

Currently it hides/displays nicely on resize just with CSS, but it all goes wrong when you resize the window and start using the Coffee.

Issue #1:

If you load the page with the content collapsible, I can stop the collapse event after resizing, but then I can never turn it on again after subsequent resizes. Or if you start with content displayed and resize till it collapses, both transitions seem to fire at once, and it briefly shows a glimmer of the content before it dissapears again.

Issue #2:

Once its collapsible, clicking the header uses a jQuery slideDown/up transition to display/hide the content, but if you hide it then resize again to make the window bigger, the content stays hidden.

I'm sure both of these are pretty simple but I've been banging my head against it almost literally all day and I can't figure it out :(

So if anyone has any insight or can lend some advice I'd be grateful.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edpxdbg8/2/) with my related CSS, Coffeescript and a content section of HTML

And the offending bit of Coffeescript:

```
$ = window.jQuery

class Collapse
  constructor: (element) ->
    @collapseBreakPoint = 400
    @element = $(element)
    @init()

  init: ->
    @setCollapseOnClick()
    @setOnResize()

  setOnResize: ->
    $(window).on 'resize', =>
      clearTimeout(resizeId)
      resizeId = setTimeout(@doneResizing, 500)

  doneResizing: =>
      if $(window).width() > @collapseBreakPoint
        @element.find('.collapse__label').off 'click'
      else
        @setCollapseOnClick()

  setCollapseOnClick: ->
    if $(window).width() < @collapseBreakPoint
      @element.find('.collapse__label').on 'click', (event) =>
        content = $(event.target).closest('[data-collapse]').find('.collapse__content')
        unless content.hasClass('open')
          content.addClass('open').stop(true, false).slideDown(500)
        else
          content.removeClass('open').stop(true, false).slideUp(500)

$.fn.collapse = ->
  new Collapse @

$.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse

$ -> $('[data-collapse]').collapse()
```

Thanks

Comment: Holy wall of text, Batman. I'm sure you could summarize what's your actual problem in just a few sentences... Make a step-by-step how to reproduce your issues, I've read it a few times and still don't get what's the problem exactly.

Comment: @Jan I didn't realise it was so difficult for most people to read 11 sentances... Aside from that, if you've ever worked on fixing bugs in anything then you'll know its better to have more information than you need than not enough.

Comment: If you've ever tried to help someone debug their code, you'll know that a clear, to-the-point description of the issue is better than a confusing myriad of information irrelevant to the problem at hand. Your code and "When I do x, I expect y but instead I get z" is enough. Also, if you're asking people to help you for free, being rude probably isn't the best way to go about it.

Comment: Is this really an issue? Someone's iPhone screen won't suddenly become desktop sized.

Answer (score 0):

To deal with this kind of things I generally do something like this:

```js
var isMobile;

function checkMobile() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
    isMobile = true;
  }
  else {
    isMobile = false;
  }
  // Mobile-specific-changes here I.E.:
  if (isMobile) {
    $('.mobSlide').addClass('collapsable');
  }
  else {
    $('.mobSlide').removeClass('collapsable');
  }
  $('p').prepend('Is mobile? | ' + isMobile);
  $('.mobSlide').text($('.mobSlide').attr('class'));
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  checkMobile();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  checkMobile();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="mobSlide"></div>
<p></p>
```

I don't even undertsand the syntax you use (CofeeScript), so this is just to show one way of solving what I understood to be the problem D: